# quaternions are less versatile than matrix?

Tags: matrices, quaternions

I am doing some research looking should I implement quaternions or matrices. What I've seem to come across is that while quaternions can be better for doing smooth rotations and dual quaternions can be used for translations along with rotations, quaternions cannot really do translations, rotations and scaling the same way that matrices can. Is that correct?

Can quaternions be used to represent uniform scales, translations and rotations in the same way as matrix can?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about 3D transformations?

Comment: quaternions  are the same as orthonormal 3D real matrixes times a real constant

Comment: Yes, and Hamilton used quaternions for it (probably invented especially for it)